# What does it mean that upon cancelling a team "team members will no longer be able to log in to Stack Overflow"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, deleted-users

Stackoverflow for Teams is really nice, but it didn't catch in our company, so we're considering cancelling it.

However, next to the option to cancel the subscription, appears the following text (emphasis is mine):

> If you cancel your Stack Overflow for Teams subscription, you will lose access to all of your Team’s content. **Additionally, your team members will no longer be able to log in to Stack Overflow.**

What does it mean that team members will not be able to log in to SO? If I have an account which I associated with this Team, will unsubscribing delete my account?

If not (because it really sounds absurd), what does this sentence mean?

I want to make sure there are no unexpected consequences to this cancellation.

Comment: Wow, I can imagine how confusing that is.

Comment: Dare you cancel your subscription?! 

Comment: Is there any support team member which can answer the question please?

Comment: Did you try to "Contact Us"?

Comment: @Scratte - thanks for the suggestion. However, the 'contact us' instructions recommend to first go through meta, and also add: "If you need to delete your account, merge accounts, or have an issue that can't be addressed by meta, please use the form below:". Seems like an issue which can be addressed by meta. I'll wait a while longer before using the general form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not the best phrasing, but it means that regular Team members immediately lose access to be able to log into the Team.

When a Team is cancelled, there's a 60 day period before it's fully deleted. During this period, Admins of a Team can access the Team in order to download the content, but cannot post or vote or anything. Meanwhile, regular users of the Team will completely be incapable of accessing the Team. This last bit is what that sentence is... not very... monoguously... meant to refer to.

To clarify from the other side of things - the only impact that cancellation of a Team has on the public Q&A account is to just delink it from the Team once it's deleted. Nothing about its login information or access will be affected.

Comment: It sounds like it would be a good idea modify the wording of that notice, so it's clearer that regular users just won't be able to log into *that* team, without affecting their ability to log into other teams or Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange itself. Frankly, if I was the one reading the notice, it would concern me too.