# Should I use my personal account or create a new one to join a company Stack Overflow Team?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-for-teams, accounts

I am being invited by my company to join their Teams account, and I don't know if it have any benefits to use my personal (this one) account to join the enterprise environment, or if it makes more sense to create a new SO account with the company email.

Does the scores and badges are shared?
Does my score for participating in the team gets reflected in my personal account?
Where can I find more info about how that interaction between account and teams work?

I have tried nothing because that will imply compromising the invitation I got to join the team, and then having to ask for a new one if it was not the correct choice.

Comment: Your score and badges from a team are completely separate from your account on main. There's no benefit either way, aside needing one less password

Comment: It's up to you. A potential problem with using your personal account is that your public and private profiles are linked, and your public activity is only a couple of clicks away from your private profile. That may or may not be desirable to you.

Comment: The potential issue I'd be most concerned about with linking my private account to a work account would be if doing so would jeopardize my control of the former after leaving my current employer.  Having seen occasional horror stories elsewhere on the net over the years, I'd be very reluctant to link any account I care about to a system that either currently does, or at some point in the future allow a 3rd party to disable or lock me out of it.

Comment: There was a rumor a while back that [users belonging to Teams that get closed would have their main SO accounts deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396962/6471538).

Comment: For me the extension MultiLogin worked best, you can also restrict it for only be used for stackoverlfow.com