# Does pressing the “Cancel subscription” button delete all accounts of users who are in the private team?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

If you scroll down on https://stackoverflow.com/c/teamName/admin/billing/plan page you would see something like this:

> Cancel your Teams subscription
>
> If you cancel your Stack Overflow for Teams subscription, you will lose access to all of your Team’s content. Additionally, your team members will no longer be able to log in to *Stack Overflow*.

(emphasis mine)

Screen-shot:

[image]

I’m not sure if this is right. Does pressing “Cancel subscription” button delete accounts of users who are in the private team?

Comment: This seems like a valid question - I'm not actually certain what it means. Certainly, if your Team members already had SO profiles, we should not be deleting those but in the case of people who only joined the Team and didn't have any other activity on SO - what would we do with their profiles - I don't know.

Comment: Related: [What does it mean that upon cancelling a team “team members will no longer be able to log in to Stack Overflow”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396962/what-does-it-mean-that-upon-cancelling-a-team-team-members-will-no-longer-be-ab). Funny as that one is a year old, but the phrasing has not changed.. !?!

Comment: The duplicate answers your question in the near term - I'm discussing whether we can revisit the wording. :)